# Flume: are Http handlers spawned into parallel threads?

Tags: flume, flume-ng

A Http source in Flume depends on a handler in charge of creating `Event` objects to be put in the channel(s). Does this handler spawn into several threads, let's say one per incoming http message? If the answer is "yes", is there any kind of pool? Which is the size of such a pool? If the answer is "no", then must I assume the incoming http messages are processed sequentially? (I hope they are not, and some kind of parallelism is implemented).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at https://github.com/apache/flume/blob/trunk/flume-ng-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/source/http/BLOBHandler.java#L63 for example (and https://github.com/apache/flume/blob/trunk/flume-ng-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/source/http/HTTPSource.java#L241 ), it looks single-threaded to me.

You can parallelize by configuring multiple HTTP Sources.

Also, the "pool" size would be defined by the channel you connect the source to, if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: I was entering SOF for auto-answering me, but you did it in advance :) And yes, I've made some tests and I've checked just one thread is run. I already thought on parallelizing the sinks when desiring "multi-threading", but never thought on the same concept for the sources. Mainly because someway my project constraints me on the number of ports I can open. Anyway, from a technical point of view your answer is correct. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, frb. Let me know if I can be of further assistance